# How to create copy-write protected pages in a module?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, copy-on-write

I am trying to make different pages protected and not protected, for example there are 10 pages in my module and I just want to make 5 pages protected (copy-on-write), other won't. How can I do that?

Edit: I am using Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Please specify what platform you are talking about (Linux, Windows etc).

Answer (score 0):

In your case you'd have to look at the Windows API: [VirtualProtect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect).
You can find the function prototype in the provided link.

You want to set the correct protection on your pages using the [PAGE_WRITECOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants) flag:

```
auto virtualAddress {reinterpret_cast<PVOID>(desiredAddress)};
SIZE_T size {0x1000}; // not guaranteed to be 0x1000
DWORD oldProtection {};
const auto newProtection {PAGE_WRITECOPY};
const auto successful = VirtualProtect(virtualAddress, size, newProtection, &oldProtection) != 0;
```